# Memory consumption in w3-total-cache vs wp-super-cache?

Tags: plugin-w3-total-cache, memory, plugin-wp-supercache

I've been suggested by my hosting to move from w3-total-cache to wp-super-cache since the later is supposed to be using less memory then the first.

Is there any knowledge about this comparison?
Is there a way to test it on my own site? (I am on a managed VPS)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a memory cache like APC or memcached, their respective admin pages will have the total memory you're using (my Wordpress installs are using 80MB with W3 Total Cache).  You could then install wp-super-cache and see what it does to your memory usage.

Comment: Thanks Dan!  If you might get around to testing this on your own thing, that would be great.  Either way, thanks for the advice.

Comment: I switched to W3 total cache from WP Super Cache several months ago.  As I recall, the memory usage hovered around 60MB, so it's less, but not less enough to make much of a difference.